# Hour angle function returning NAN.0 - PHP

Tags: php, math

I have the following function:

```
$h = -0.31415926535898;
$phi = 1.193418536022;
$d = 0.27445457443182;

function hourAngle($h, $phi, $d): float
{
    $a = acos((sin($h) - sin($phi) * sin($d)) / (cos($phi) * cos($d)));
    return $a;
}
```

With the above value the returned value is NAN.0
and I am not sure why?

The methods I am using are from github.com/gregseth/suncalc-php and using like this

```
    $date = '2022-05-04'; 
    $newLat = 68.377845306742; 
    $newLon = -104.04602008881; 
    $sunriseTransit = sunCalc(new DateTime($date), $newLat, $newLon)['dawn']->format('H:i'); 
    
    function sunCalc($date, $lat, $long): array { 
    $suncalc = new SunCalc($date, $lat, $long); 
    return $suncalc->getSunTimes(); 
    }
```

shows the error. It looks like it already converts to rad and additionally it seems to only happen when e.g. latitude is above 70 degree which when converted to radians is above 1.

Comment: As detailed in documentation, [the `cos()`](https://www.php.net/cos) and [`sin()`](https://www.php.net/sin) functions accept values in radians, meaning a range from -1 to 1.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php

Comment: The methods I am using are from 
https://github.com/gregseth/suncalc-php 

and using like this 
$date = '2022-05-04';
$newLat = 68.377845306742;
$newLon = -104.04602008881;

$sunriseTransit = sunCalc(new DateTime($date), $newLat, $newLon)['dawn']->format('H:i');

function sunCalc($date, $lat, $long): array
{
    $suncalc = new SunCalc($date, $lat, $long);
    return $suncalc->getSunTimes();
} 

shows the error. It looks like it alread converts to rad

Comment: I think $h should not be negative